# My qqnorm and qqline graph is not showing up

Tags: r

```
# Download the dataset
SP500dailydat<-tq_get("^GSPC", from = '2000-02-01', to = "2020-02-01",get = "stock.prices")

# Simple returns 
getSymbols("^GSPC", from='2000-02-01',to='2020-02-01')

#Calculate simple returns
GSPC_Sim_Returns=(diff(GSPC$GSPC.Adjusted, lag=1))

# Squared returns 
GSPC_Sqd_Ret=(GSPC_Sim_Returns)^2

# Absolute returns 
GSPC_Daily_Ret=(GSPC_Sim_Returns)/100

# Plot the returns 
plot(SP500dailydat$date,GSPC_Sim_Returns, main="Simple Daily Returns")
plot(SP500dailydat$date,GSPC_Sqd_Ret, main="Daily Squared Returns")
plot(SP500dailydat$date,GSPC_Daily_Ret, main="Absolute Daily Returns")

#Question 2 
# Distribution of Returns 
# Histogram
hist(GSPC_Daily_Ret)
# qq norm plots
qqnorm(GSPC_Daily_Ret)
qqline(GSPC_Daily_Ret, col = "steelblue", lwd = 2)
```

After the qqnorm and qqline my graph is not showing up I don't know why. i tried to see if i didnt install the right packages and thats not the case. im not getting an error code the graph itself just is not showing up.

Comment: please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: i dont have a data set. i imported in R using the getsymbols.

Comment: You are using `getSymbols()` to get the data, but you are not assigning the data to anything. Then you call functions on `GSPC`, but do not define that object. Do you get errors like "Object GSPC does not exist"? Try `GSPC <- getSymbols("^GSPC", from='2000-02-01',to='2020-02-01')`